# How to set the background-color of a div as primary theme color in Angular 2 Material

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm using one of the angular 2 material's theme. I'm able to use the theme colors on material components like button, toolbar using color="primary". But I'm not able to figure out how to theme a div. I don't want to hardcode the hash in .css file since if i decide to change the theme it'll require changes at all places. Am i missing something? What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Indeed, you cannot use `color="primary"` on every HTML element.

What I did is a class called `color-primary`

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();

$primary: mat-palette($mat-deep-purple, 600, 500, 900);
$accent: mat-palette($mat-amber, A400, A300, A600);


.color-primary {
  color: mat-color($primary);
}

.color-accent {
  color: mat-color($accent);
}
```

Of course, I've set the color here but you can create another class, for example : `background-color-primary`.

*(here's the link of my sample project : [Pizza-Sync](https://github.com/maxime1992/pizza-sync/blob/5212a29ee9be916383f759a3a129f7b580ed32ea/frontend/src/styles/shared/_utils.scss#L11)).*

Comment: Looks like I'll have to use SCSS. I was doing everything with CSS till now. Any solution with just CSS you maybe aware of?

Comment: No sorry, I only know how to do that with SCSS. Well ... In fact you might define it statically but if you change the theme it wouldn't change it ... You should really go with scss ;) Plus, you won't have to change anything at the beginning and you can use sccs functionalities little step by little step to make your life easier :)

Comment: I did it statically only for the initial version but it defies the whole purpose of theming itself. Well now I've switched to scss and things are working fine now. Thanks man

Comment: Though slightly out of context, do you know where can I find some reference/doc for the material classes I can use like mat-elevation-z5 etc..

Comment: Glad you did it, scss is great you'll like it. Take a quick look to its doc so you can have a better idea of what you can do ;) And no I don't ... Still young and we don't have everything yet :)
If your app is still small, maybe you'd like to use [Prime NG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/) or [Teradata Covalent](https://teradata.github.io/covalent/#/components/paging) ;)

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use the defined palettes for BACKGROUND and FOREGROUND. To add properties if you wish.

[See my answer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43919927/angular-material2-theming-how-to-set-app-background/45028242#45028242)