# Angular Material2 theming - how to set app background?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am building an angular2 app using angular material2. I am trying to set the background of my application "the correct way", but I can't figure out how.

I found a class I can use on my `<body>` element: `mat-app-background` which I can add, that gives me a default color (depending on whether I'm using the light or dark themes).

I wish to define this background color to use my brands' color, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

In `_theming.scss` it is defined like so:

```
// Mixin that renders all of the core styles that depend on the theme.
@mixin mat-core-theme($theme) {
  @include mat-ripple-theme($theme);
  @include mat-option-theme($theme);
  @include mat-pseudo-checkbox-theme($theme);

  // Wrapper element that provides the theme background when the
  // user's content isn't inside of a `md-sidenav-container`.
  .mat-app-background {
    $background: map-get($theme, background);
    background-color: mat-color($background, background);
  }
  ...
}
```

So I thought it would make sense to try adding the background color to my custom theme, somehow, but I couldn't understand how to do so.

On the Material2 [theming](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/theming.md) documentation it only says:

"In Angular Material, a theme is created by composing multiple palettes. In particular, a theme consists of:

- A primary palette: colors most widely used across all screens and components.
- An accent palette: colors used for the floating action button and interactive elements.
- A warn palette: colors used to convey error state.
- A foreground palette: colors for text and icons.
- A background palette: colors used for element backgrounds.
  "

How can I add my background to the theme, or do it in any other way?

Comment: Would you consider accepting an answer if any of them seem particularly helpful?

Comment: @JakeStoeffler Sure, although I cannot verify it works since we've abandoned our Angular project, and I can't even remember what we ended up doing in the end ^_^

Answer (score 80, accepted):

If you want to change the theme's background color for the entire app in a clean way, you can override your theme with the following.

```css
// Set custom background color
$custom-background-color: map_get($mat-blue-grey, 50);

// -or- Can set colour by hex value too
$custom-background-color: #628cc9;

$background: map-get($theme, background);
$background: map_merge($background, (background: $custom-background-color));
$theme: map_merge($theme, (background: $background));
```

This assumes you have already set up your `$theme` using `mat-light-theme` or `mat-dark-theme`. Of course you can substitute `$mat-blue-grey` for a color map of your choosing.

Here is a full example of how I am using this.  I have the following in a file called `theme.scss`, which is included in my `angular.json` "styles" entry:

```css
// Include the common styles for Angular Material. We include this here so that you only
// have to load a single css file for Angular Material in your app.
// Be sure that you only ever include this mixin once!
@include mat-core;

// Define the palettes for your theme using the Material Design palettes available in palette.scss
// (imported above). For each palette, you can optionally specify a default, lighter, and darker
// hue.
$primary: mat-palette($mat-red, 600, 400, 900);
$accent: mat-palette($mat-blue-grey, 500, 200, 700);
$background-color: map_get($mat-blue-grey, 50);

// The warn palette is optional (defaults to red).
$warn: mat-palette($mat-blue);

// Create the theme object (a Sass map containing all of the palettes).
$theme: mat-light-theme($primary, $accent, $warn);

// Insert custom background color
$background: map-get($theme, background);
$background: map_merge($background, (background: $background-color));
$theme: map_merge($theme, (background: $background));

// Include theme styles for core and each component used in your app.
// Alternatively, you can import and @include the theme mixins for each component
// that you are using.
@include angular-material-theme($theme);
@include my-app-theme($theme);
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. I just edited the example code to show how to use hex colour directly. It was not obvious to me from the start. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @ppumkin  could you show an example of how to use this?  i'm new to scss and theming.  i keep getting an error on map_merge.. i'm not sure if i need a mixin or what.  it says this isn't valid css and shows my theme. within ( )

Comment: @Jesse I was getting similar errors. I think you need to to include specific files. The error relates to the map_merge not able to find the mixin variable within the context of the file. Let me check my files.. maybe I can update this answer a bit more. Jake I hope you don't mind? (But this is a very good answer any way - Probably should be the accepted one)

Comment: @ppumkin @Jesse I have added a full example of how I'm using this. It's possible you might also need to `@import '~@angular/material/theming';` if you haven't done so elsewhere.

Comment: Excellent.  It's important to note, the theme-map has a background property that is the background-map.  In the background-map, there is another background property, as well as numerous other properties.  The property I wanted to target was background > card (property that determines the background color for the mat-menu).  Look for at the variable `$mat-dark-theme-background` in the `_theming.scss` file for all the properties available in the background map.

Comment: How to use the background in any html?

Comment: With Angular 10 this doesn't work anymore. Did you found any other workaround like this?

Comment: Just found a way. Install `https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-recursive-map-merge`, and then: ```// NG10+ Have a nested `color` map.
$palette-color        : map-get($theme, color);
$background: map-get($palette-color, background);
$background: map_merge($background, (background: $background));
$theme: map_merge($theme, (background: $background));
$theme: recursive-map-merge($theme, (color: (background: $background)));```

Comment: Same for `foreground`.

Comment: not working for me....  all colors changes except for the background :(

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working for Angular 11

Answer (score 40):

Not exactly answer to your question, but I guess many people will end up here searching for "how to set app background color".

In your `project/index.html` set your body class to `mat-app-background`

```
<body class="mat-app-background">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

And make sure in your `project/angular.json` you have:

```
        "styles": [
          "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/YOUR_STYLE.css",
          ...
        ],
```

Answer (score 14):

## Angular 12

```scss
// For example Orange palette
$orange-palette: mat.define-palette(mat.$orange-palette);

// Define theme
$theme: mat.define-dark-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $orange-palette,
    accent: $orange-palette
  )
));

// Get color param from our theme
$palette-color : map-get($theme, color);
// Get background param from color param
$background: map-get($palette-color, background);
// $background also has background param contains color, set it to red (for example)
$background: map_merge($background, (background: red));
// Set background param for palette
$palette-color: map_merge($palette-color, (background: $background));
// Set palette for theme
$theme: map_merge($theme, (color: $palette-color));

@include mat.all-component-themes($theme);
```

Or with function:

```scss
@function mat-set-background($theme, $backgroundColor) {
  $palette-color : map-get($theme, color);
  $background: map-get($palette-color, background);
  $background: map_merge($background, (background: $backgroundColor));
  $palette-color: map_merge($palette-color, (background: $background));
  @return map_merge($theme, (color: $palette-color));
}

$orange-palette: mat.define-palette(mat.$orange-palette);

$theme: mat.define-dark-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $orange-palette,
    accent: $orange-palette
  )
));

$theme: mat-set-background($theme, #FF0000);
@include mat.all-component-themes($theme);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This answer worked for me once I added the class "mat-app-background" to the element/wrapper I wished to apply the background colour to. Maybe obvious but I certainly overlooked it so adding here in case others make the same mistake I made.

Comment: Been searching for hours but couldn't find a solution, what if I want to make background gradient? it looks like `background` attribute being represented as `background-color` in the css file so `linear-gradient(...)` etc won't work. Any solution to this?

Answer (score 13):

edit: This strategy involves replacing Material functionality. for most cases, I would recommend Jake Stoeffler's answer above.

If you want to set the background colors, you likely want to customize the entire background and foreground palette by emulating the [mat-light-theme](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/3352201eabcf66c23e6c2297b800828003eaf0fc/src/lib/core/theming/_theming.scss#L62) or mat-dark-theme functions with your own replacement. Your replacement would include your own palettes instead of the [mat-light-theme-foreground](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/48ff4ba74a92924dc42ae2fd1592351c630fbb1b/src/lib/core/theming/_palette.scss#L704) and background palettes.

example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-custom-background?file=theme.scss

I don't know if this method is recommended or officially supported.

Comment: This is very nice for fine tuning the theme but if you want the default themes but only want to change one or two properties, look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49434227/706363 by Jake below.

Answer (score 6):

see : [palette theme scss on github Angular (2) Material (2)](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/core/theming/_palette.scss)

Extract of the code:

```css
// Background palette for light themes.
$mat-light-theme-background: (
  status-bar: map_get($mat-grey, 300),
  app-bar:    map_get($mat-grey, 100),
  background: map_get($mat-grey, 50),
  hover:      rgba(black, 0.04), // TODO(kara): check style with Material Design UX
  card:       white,
  dialog:     white,
  disabled-button: $black-12-opacity,
  raised-button: white,
  focused-button: $black-6-opacity,
  selected-button: map_get($mat-grey, 300),
  selected-disabled-button: map_get($mat-grey, 400),
  disabled-button-toggle: map_get($mat-grey, 200),
);

// Background palette for dark themes.
$mat-dark-theme-background: (
  status-bar: black,
  app-bar:    map_get($mat-grey, 900),
  background: #303030,
  hover:      rgba(white, 0.04), // TODO(kara): check style with Material Design UX
  card:       map_get($mat-grey, 800),
  dialog:     map_get($mat-grey, 800),
  disabled-button: $white-12-opacity,
  raised-button: map-get($mat-grey, 800),
  focused-button: $white-6-opacity,
  selected-button: map_get($mat-grey, 900),
  selected-disabled-button: map_get($mat-grey, 800),
  disabled-button-toggle: map_get($mat-grey, 1000),
);

// Foreground palette for light themes.
$mat-light-theme-foreground: (
  base:              black,
  divider:           $black-12-opacity,
  dividers:          $black-12-opacity,
  disabled:          rgba(black, 0.38),
  disabled-button:   rgba(black, 0.38),
  disabled-text:     rgba(black, 0.38),
  hint-text:         rgba(black, 0.38),
  secondary-text:    rgba(black, 0.54),
  icon:              rgba(black, 0.54),
  icons:             rgba(black, 0.54),
  text:              rgba(black, 0.87),
  slider-off:        rgba(black, 0.26),
  slider-off-active: rgba(black, 0.38),
);

// Foreground palette for dark themes.
$mat-dark-theme-foreground: (
  base:              white,
  divider:           $white-12-opacity,
  dividers:          $white-12-opacity,
  disabled:          rgba(white, 0.3),
  disabled-button:   rgba(white, 0.3),
  disabled-text:     rgba(white, 0.3),
  hint-text:         rgba(white, 0.3),
  secondary-text:    rgba(white, 0.7),
  icon:              white,
  icons:             white,
  text:              white,
  slider-off:        rgba(white, 0.3),
  slider-off-active: rgba(white, 0.3),
);
```

Comment: Can you provide a step-by-step explanation where I can define my new theme palette, and use it as background for the entire app (preferably on the `<body>` element, as described In the question?

Comment: I just refedined these values with my own ones before call `mat-light-theme($app-primary, $app-accent, $app-warn)` and it worked :D

Comment: Please provide info about implementing this

Comment: Not a lot of help for noobs just learning Angular Material 4. I mean, the hyperlink to the source is already **everywhere**. A little hint as to how to override these properly, would be a much better answer.

Comment: Working for light theme but not for the dark theme

Comment: The forground and background variables evolve with version (branch or tags), remember to change this value with your version of Meterial.

Comment: For anybody looking at this and going WTF is this and how to use it.. It is basically the CORE variables used by Materials SassyCSS - If you go GitHub and look at the example themes.. this is what you will see there. You can use this to create your own fully customised colours while still being able to plug it in to Material. But this is on the lower end of Advanced and isnt obvios... since they don't want you to do it this way.. You can.. but you probably shouldn't -- But if you need to then you can do this. I did a +1 now.. but only days after fully understanding the entire structure.

Comment: here is some good explanation of how it works https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-a-custom-theme-in-angular-material-d47122a1e361

Answer (score 6):

Lately, from Material 10.x onwards, the theming methods are getting revamped. With the new approach `mat-light-theme` or `mat-dark-theme` only accepts a config object for colors. This is what I've found in the comments :

> Previously in Angular Material, theme objects contained the color
> configuration directly. With the recent refactoring of the theming
> system to allow for density and typography configurations, this is no
> longer the case.

At the moment these methods support legacy approach as well, but I hope soon that will be declared as a breaking change. Since we can't merge the new background to theme object as before, the accepted answer might not work anymore.

What I did instead of that, I've updated the `$mat-light-theme-background` pallete with my custom background, before creating the new theme and that did the job.

```
$app-primary: mat-palette($md-light);
$app-accent: mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);
$app-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);
$custom-background-color: map_get($md-light, 50);

$mat-light-theme-background: map_merge($mat-light-theme-background, (background: $custom-background-color));

$light-theme: mat-light-theme((
    color: (
        primary: $app-primary,
        accent: $app-accent,
        warn:  $app-warn
    )
));
```

Note: `$md-light` is the custom pallet that I have defined for my application, you could use any other values.
Also I have tried passing 'background' along with the other color properties which didn't work some reason.

The way themes are included is also slightly changed. Now there is new method called `angular-material-color` for including the themes.

```
@include angular-material-color($light-theme);
```

Comment: true that. we only need to override what is there in core

Answer (score 3):

There is also a mixing for colors like this:

```
.your-class-here {
   background: mat-color($mat-grey, 700, 0.9);
}
```

When looking at angular material components you can assign a color like this.

```
<md-toolbar color="primary">
</md-toolbar>
```

That will make your toolbar the color of your primary color.

also make sure to look at _theming.scss file in angular material.

so you can use those mixins to just pull a color from your palette.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Are you suggesting I create a global CSS class for the background? I thought it would be nicer to add this to the theme so I could access via the `color` directive (like you suggested: `color="background"`). Is it possible to do that?

Comment: well If you are trying to add a background for your website, then you probably should just use the body tag and you can pull a color with the mixin.  If you are writing a custom component using material or for material then you should incorporate the theme colors for automatic colors, assuming someone else would use your component you wrote (datepicker, or etc)  If you use a built in material component then they expose the [color]=primary, that does't just exist in normal angular or html out of the box.

Comment: How do I set the background for the `<body>` tag then? Other than hard-coding inside `index.html` something like: `<body style="background-color: #123123">`? The `<app-root>` element is INSIDE the `<body>`...

Comment: by making a global style sheet, putting the refrence to that style sheet in your index.html (angular-cli comes with one already) and in that global style sheet if you did  body { background-color: #123123; } that would globally set the BG color.

Answer (score 3):

This solution work at Angular Material 12

_foreground-background-light.scss

```
@use 'sass:map';
@use '~@angular/material' as mat;


$light-primary-color: map_get($md-white-blue-cotcha, 500);
$light-secondary-color: map_get($md-red-cotcha, 500);

$dark-primary-text: rgba(black, 0.87);
$dark-secondary-text: rgba(black, 0.54);
$dark-dividers: rgba(black, 0.12);
$dark-disabled-text: rgba(black, 0.38);
$dark-focused: rgba(black, 0.12);

$light-primary-text: white;

$grey-palette: (
  50: #fafafa,
  100: #f5f5f5,
  200: #eeeeee,
  300: #e0e0e0,
  400: #bdbdbd,
  500: #9e9e9e,
  600: #757575,
  700: #616161,
  800: #424242,
  900: #212121,
  A100: #ffffff,
  A200: #eeeeee,
  A400: #bdbdbd,
  A700: #616161,
  contrast: (
    50: $dark-primary-text,
    100: $dark-primary-text,
    200: $dark-primary-text,
    300: $dark-primary-text,
    400: $dark-primary-text,
    500: $dark-primary-text,
    600: $light-primary-text,
    700: $light-primary-text,
    800: $light-primary-text,
    900: $light-primary-text,
    A100: $dark-primary-text,
    A200: $dark-primary-text,
    A400: $dark-primary-text,
    A700: $light-primary-text,
  )
);


// get color of light-theme
$mat-light-theme-color: map_get($mat-light-theme, 'color');

// get Foreground palette for light theme
$light-theme-foreground-palette: map_get($mat-light-theme-color, 'foreground');

// set Foreground palette for light theme.
$light-theme-foreground-palette: map_merge($light-theme-foreground-palette,
  (
    'base':              black,
    'divider':           $dark-dividers,
    'dividers':          $dark-dividers,
    'disabled':          $dark-disabled-text,
    'disabled-button':   rgba(black, 0.26),
    'disabled-text':     $dark-disabled-text,
    'elevation':         black,
    'hint-text':         $dark-disabled-text,
    'secondary-text':    $dark-secondary-text,
    'icon':              rgba(black, 0.54),
    'icons':             rgba(black, 0.54),
    'text':              rgba(black, 0.87),
    'slider-min':        rgba(black, 0.87),
    'slider-off':        rgba(black, 0.26),
    'slider-off-active': rgba(black, 0.38),
  )
);

// get Background palette for light theme.
$light-theme-background-palette: map_get($mat-light-theme-color, 'background');

// set Background palette for light theme.
$light-theme-background-palette: map_merge($light-theme-background-palette,
  (
    'status-bar':               map.get($grey-palette, 300),
    'app-bar':                  map.get($grey-palette, 100),
    'background':               $light-primary-color,
    'hover':                    rgba(black, 0.04), // TODO(kara)': check style with Material Design UX
    'card':                   white,
    'dialog':                 white,
    'disabled-button':          rgba(black, 0.12),
    'raised-button':          white,
    'focused-button':           $dark-focused,
    'selected-button':          map.get($grey-palette, 300),
    'selected-disabled-button': map.get($grey-palette, 400),
    'disabled-button-toggle':   map.get($grey-palette, 200),
    'unselected-chip':          map.get($grey-palette, 300),
    'disabled-list-option':     map.get($grey-palette, 200),
    'tooltip':                  map.get($grey-palette, 700),
  )
);

//set color for light theme.
$mat-light-theme-color: map_merge($mat-light-theme-color, 
  (
    'foreground': $light-theme-foreground-palette,
    'background': $light-theme-background-palette
  )
);
  
// set light theme.
$mat-light-theme: map_merge($mat-light-theme, 
  (
    'color': $mat-light-theme-color
  )
);
```

styles.scss

```
@use '~@angular/material' as mat;


@include mat.core();


@import './styles/foreground-background-light';
```

good implementation

Comment: Would you please share how this is helpful, by adding some comments/explanation to your code so people, not just OP, can understand how your answer can be used.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you declare a background colour in a variables file (assuming you're using sass) then simply import it where needed. For example:-

```
@import '../config/variables';

body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: $brand-primary;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! Yeah, I do have a variables files, where I can add my custom colors as variables. Where should I add the `body` CSS rule, so it will be accessible on `index.html`? Since Material2 encapsulates the styles to the proper component, the `<body>` element is out of any component scope. That's where `.mat-app-background` comes into the picture, because it works, but.I am not sure how to override it...

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it "properly" - only workarounds and hacks. Your theme can define primary, secondary, and warn palettes, but not foreground and background palettes. The probable reason why there isn't a direct/easy way to do this in Angular Material is that according to Material Design you shouldn't do this. Color is meant to be used in a specific way to highlight and style various elements according to your theme, but background and foreground colors for plain content is meant to be either dark or light grey - not colored. If you really need to do this, the other suggestions about redefining the background theme or using your own class should be sufficient.

Comment: Yea... but we are people and some of are not as black and white as Google :D Jakes answer below provides a very nice, simple way to change one setting, while using the default styles.

Comment: Thanks pumpkin - my response basically says the same thing about other ways to do it, although your boyfriend Jake's answer was posted more than two months after mine. ;)

Comment: It's `ppumkin` for a reason ( I assure you my IQ is well above 100) and I am happily married MALE thanks :D  I know he posted it later, that is why I commented - Because answers can be updated YEARS later as technology changes or better ways are created.

Comment: i need help using either of these methods!  what if i want to set a custom grey?  also i cannot get jakes answer to work :))))

Answer (score 1):

I found that the accepted solution does not work for angular 9. But with a little adjustment, you can make it work.

The original question was how to add a background-color variable to a custom material theme. You can do the following.

`styles.scss`

```
// Only import this one time in your project
@include mat-core;

@import '~@angular/material/theming';

// Divine what you want the 'default' variables to look like
$primary: mat-palette($mat-grey, 700, 300, 900);
$accent: mat-palette($mat-blue-grey, 400);
$warn: mat-palette($mat-red, 500);

// create a theme. This can be mat-dark-theme or mat-light-theme
$theme: mat-dark-theme(
  $primary,
  $accent,
  $warn
);

/* This is where you create your custom variable map
Make sure that the variable name you chose is one that does not exist in 
the $theme map. In the accept answer, it uses $background but this one is 
already taken. By using for example, 'background-of-main' you are sure 
that there is no collision */
// You can choose any #hexa color code you want
$custom-variables: (background-of-main: #48494d);

// Merge theme and the custom variables together
$theme: map_merge($theme, $custom-variables);

// Expose custom theme globally
@include angular-material-theme($theme);
```

In the component where you want to use the background variable, you can do the following. I create a separate file for the code below called:

`<path-to-component>/custom-background-component-theme.scss`

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

@mixin custom-background-component-theme($theme) {
  $background: map-get($theme, background-of-main);

  <css-selector> {
    background-color: $background;
  }
```

The final step is to call the `custom-background-component-theme` mixin in the styles.scss. Therefore the final version of the styles.scss is:

`styles.scss`

```
// Only import this one time in your project
@include mat-core;

@import '~@angular/material/theming';

// Divine what you want the 'default' styles to look like
$primary: mat-palette($mat-grey, 700, 300, 900);
$accent: mat-palette($mat-blue-grey, 400);
$warn: mat-palette($mat-red, 500);

// create a theme. This can be mat-dark-theme or mat-light-theme
$theme: mat-dark-theme(
  $primary,   
  $accent,
  $warn
);

/* This is where you create your custom variable map
Make sure that the variable name you chose is one that does not exist in 
the $theme map. In the accept answer, it uses $background but this one is 
already taken. By using for example, 'background-of-main' you are 
sure that there is not collision */
// You can choose any #hexa color code you want
$custom-variables: (background-of-main: #48494d);

// Merge theme and the custom variables together
$theme: map_merge($theme, $custom-variables);

// Expose custom theme globally
@include angular-material-theme($theme);

// Import custom mixin
@import './<path-to-component>/custom-background-component-theme.scss';

// Insert custom theme into component styling
@include custom-background-component-theme($theme);
```

This should do the job!

Answer (score 1):

Adding my experience from trying to do this in Angular Material 12, (specifically: `"@angular/material": "~12.2.0-sha-7a97590aeb"`) which seemed to change a lot of these functions.  Not a very experienced webdev, so bear with me.

I was looking to have a light/dark/black theme, where the black theme is a dark theme with background set to black.  I started from the example in [docs](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#multiple-themes-in-one-file):

```
$dark-theme: mat.define-dark-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $dark-primary,
    accent: $dark-accent,
    warn: $dark-warn,
  )
));
```

At this point `$dark-theme` holds an object with a bunch of style stuff in it.  The object path to the background color is `$dark-theme.color.background.background`, which you have to extract and set using `map_get` & `map_merge`.

```
$background-color: black;

// note- this is a reference, but will get it's own copy later on
$black-theme: $dark-theme;

// get $black-theme-color.color.background
$black-theme-color-config: map_get($black-theme, 'color');
$black-theme-color-config-background: map_get($black-theme-color-config, 'background');

// set $black-theme-color.color.background.background
$black-theme-color-config-background: map_merge($black-theme-color-config-background, ('background': $background-color));
$black-theme-color-config: map_merge($black-theme-color-config, ('background': $black-theme-color-config-background));
$black-theme: map_merge($black-theme, ('color': $black-theme-color-config));
```

At this point, `$black-theme` is identical to `$dark-theme` except the background is now `#000000`, which meets my needs.

I doubt this is supported and could change in the future, so use at your own risk.

I did find an issue requesting this be added, so if you want it officially supported, you can vote for it at https://github.com/angular/components/issues/6244.

Answer (score 0):

for extra solution if previous didn't work i angular material 2 working with **encapsulation style** so whatever you gonna do you can't customize angular material component from outside so an ideal solution for that i always use try this

1- you can use this hack that gonna give you possibilities to customize angular material component if you want to by set `ViewEncapsulation.None`

```
//test.component.ts
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: '.....',
  styleUrls: ['....'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

or

2- if you want just to change background you can simple try this

```
//style.css (main style file)
html, body {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}
```

this gonna change the whole background color of all your app

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party. I know this is Angular Material 2 but, google leads here material. Adding my findings.

Angular Material does make it a little hard to change background and foreground styles in Material 11.2. I dug through the theme files to see how it all works.

To change the theme background. Let's say you have `core.scss` file that has your theme related styles. [Material Doc](https://v11.material.angular.io/guide/theming#defining-a-custom-theme)

```
$candy-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$candy-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);
$candy-app-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);
```

you change the theme background by modifying `$mat-light-theme-background` for light theme and dark for dark theme. Use `map-merge` to prevent unwanted issues.

```
$mat-light-theme-background: map-merge($mat-light-theme-background, (
   app-bar: map-get($mat-grey, A100), // Change color to whatever you want.
   background: map-get($mat-grey, A100) // Change color to whatever you want. 
));

// Follow by calling mat-light-theme(//) or mat-dark-theme(//)
```

This will change the background of the Angular application.