# Theme angular material pagenator background colour

Tags: angular-material2

Hi I'm trying to change the background of a `mat-pagenator` control in an angular project.

However it appears that the pagenator always appears white. Regardless of the background-color I set in the application.

**styles.scss**

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();
$sample-material-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$sample-material-app-accent: mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);
$sample-material-app-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);
$sample-material-app-theme: mat-light-theme($sample-material-app-primary, $sample-material-app-accent, $sample-material-app-warn);
$background: map-get($sample-material-app-theme, background);
$background: map_merge($background, (background: #FF1010));
$theme: map_merge($sample-material-app-theme, (background: $background));
@include angular-material-theme($theme);
@include mat-paginator-theme($theme);
//Just so we can see a background color
html, body { height: 100%; background-color: bisque }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<mat-form-field>
  List length:
  <input matInput [(ngModel)]="length">
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
  Page size:
  <input matInput [(ngModel)]="pageSize">
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field>
  Page size options:
  <input matInput
         [ngModel]="pageSizeOptions"
         (ngModelChange)="setPageSizeOptions($event)">
</mat-form-field>

<mat-paginator [length]="length"
              [pageSize]="pageSize"
              [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
              (page)="pageEvent = $event">
</mat-paginator>

<div *ngIf="pageEvent">
  <h5>Page Change Event Properties</h5>
  <div>List length: {{pageEvent.length}}</div>
  <div>Page size: {{pageEvent.pageSize}}</div>
  <div>Page index: {{pageEvent.pageIndex}}</div>
</div>
```

result:
[image: Example showing that background is set to white regardless]

the desired result is to set a color for the background of this component(and some others)

The way I'm trying to set the background is based on [Angular Material2 theming - how to set app background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43919927/angular-material2-theming-how-to-set-app-background)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `<mat-paginator>` inherits its background colour from card not from the `background` property.

The same seems to be true for `<mat-table>` so to set the default styles of these the following worked: (note this is an ugly colour just to prove the colour works)

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();
$sample-material-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$sample-material-app-accent: mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);
$sample-material-app-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);
$sample-material-app-theme: mat-light-theme($sample-material-app-primary, $sample-material-app-accent, $sample-material-app-warn);
$background: map-get($sample-material-app-theme, background);
$bg-color: #FF1010;
$background: map_merge($background, (background: $bg-color, card: $bg-color, dialog:$bg-color));
$theme: map_merge($sample-material-app-theme, (background: $background));
@include angular-material-theme($theme);
@include mat-paginator-theme($theme);
//Just so we can see a background color
html, body { height: 100%; background-color: bisque }
```

**Note** I also added dialog into this as it was also set to `white` and its likely that it needs the same background colour.

Comment: Your answer is so very precious ! I could not find anything like it on the whole web of tutorials and other mediums. One thing would help further, you use some attributes in the merge call, like card and dialog. Would you know where to have the complete list ? I'm interested in the toolbar.

Comment: I have now found the background palette with all its properties. I need to figure out how it is to be used.

Comment: Sorry Stephane, I generally don't work with angular or frontend at all. This was found after stepping through different code to see where it was getting its values from. I don't remember the steps.