# Angular Material coloring app background dynamically does not work

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm trying to achieve that the background of my app is a color defined by the currently used theme. This does not really work.

What I've tried: [Angular Material2 theming - how to set app background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43919927/angular-material2-theming-how-to-set-app-background). I've tried to use the accepted solution of this posting but for me only the background of all components is set and gets overwritten by the theme. I don't know how to handle it.

How it looks like (white part with no content should be dark as well):
[image]

I've copied the theming action like in this tutorial and everything works fine there: https://medium.com/grensesnittet/dynamic-themes-in-angular-material-b6dc0c88dfd7

app.component.html:

```html
<div
  [ngClass]="{'default-theme': (selectedTheme | async) === 'default-theme', 'dark-theme': (selectedTheme | async) === 'dark-theme', 'light-theme': (selectedTheme | async) === 'light-theme', 'nature-theme': (selectedTheme | async) === 'nature-theme'}">
  <div class="mat-app-background">
    <app-header></app-header>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

index.html:

```html
<body class="mat-app-background">
  <app-root>
  </app-root>
</body>
```

material-theme.scss:

```css
@import "~@angular/material/theming";
@import "./component-themes";

@include mat-core();

$primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$accent: mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);
$warn: mat-palette($mat-red);
$theme: mat-light-theme($primary, $accent, $warn);

@include angular-material-theme($theme);
@include component-themes($theme);

.dark-theme {
  color: $light-primary-text;
  $dark-primary: mat-palette($mat-grey, 700, 300, 900);
  $dark-accent: mat-palette($mat-blue-grey, 400);
  $dark-warn: mat-palette($mat-red, 500);
  $dark-theme: mat-dark-theme($dark-primary, $dark-accent, $dark-warn);
  $bp: mat-palette($mat-red);

  @include angular-material-theme($dark-theme);
  @include component-themes($dark-theme);
}
```

styles.scss:

```css
@import "./material-theme";
@import "~@angular/material/theming";

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  // background-color: mat-color($bp);
}
```

Themes are set through the app-component.ts:

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.themeService.setTheme(localStorage.getItem("theme"));
    this.selectedTheme = this.themeService.theme;
    this.selectedTheme.subscribe(data => {
      const overlayContainerClasses = this.overlayContainer.getContainerElement()
        .classList;
      const themeClassesToRemove = Array.from(
        overlayContainerClasses
      ).filter((item: string) => item.includes("-theme"));
      if (themeClassesToRemove.length) {
        overlayContainerClasses.remove(...themeClassesToRemove);
      }
      overlayContainerClasses.add(data);
    });
  }
```

So what is the best approach to get it done?

Answer (score 2):

I had issues with the background color as well when switching between a dark and light theme, because it was not sufficient to change the CSS class on the OverlayContainer, I had to change the CSS class on the body element as well.

Here the code that worked for me:

(you could find a full working code example at https://github.com/toongeorges/angular-electron-material-design/commit/4d91f9c21ed24b853da8284099e641676d620826)

- in source/index.html:

```html
<body class="mat-app-background">
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
```

- in src/styles.scss:

```css
//default theme
@include angular-material-theme($dark-theme);

.light-theme {
    @include angular-material-theme($light-theme);
}

.dark-theme {
    @include angular-material-theme($dark-theme);
}
```

- in src/app/app.component.html:

```html
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent" mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" aria-label="Select Theme">
        Select Theme
    </button>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
        <button mat-menu-item (click)="onSetTheme('dark-theme')">
            <mat-icon svgIcon="brightness-2"></mat-icon>
            <span>Dark Theme</span>
        </button>
        <button mat-menu-item (click)="onSetTheme('light-theme')">
            <mat-icon svgIcon="brightness-7"></mat-icon>
            <span>Light Theme</span>
        </button>
    </mat-menu>
```

- in src/app/app.component.ts:

```js
  onSetTheme(theme: string) {
    if (theme === this.componentCssClass) {
      //ignore change
    } else {
      if (theme == 'dark-theme') {
        this.resetTheme(theme);
      } else if (theme == 'light-theme') {
        this.resetTheme(theme);
      } else {
        console.error("Unknown theme: " + theme);
      }
    }
  }

  resetTheme(theme: string) {
    const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

    if (this.componentCssClass) {
      //remove the old style
      body.classList.remove(this.componentCssClass);
      this.overlayContainer.getContainerElement().classList.remove(this.componentCssClass);
    }

    this.componentCssClass = theme;
    //set the new style
    body.classList.add(this.componentCssClass);
    this.overlayContainer.getContainerElement().classList.add(this.componentCssClass);
  }
```