# How to change application background color for the Angular Material light and dark themes?

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

Is it possible to change a theme property in order to change the background color for the light and dark Angular Material themes?

[There are simple ways to do this as mentioned in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43919927/angular-material2-theming-how-to-set-app-background), but I'm wondering if we can change a known property inside the SASS theme map.  Something like:

```
$background: mat.get($theme, background);
$background: map.merge($background, (app-background: orange)) //Change the background color to orange
$theme: mat.merge($theme, (background: $background)); //replace the background with a updated background
```

Where `app-background` is a standard property already included in the Angular theme ...

Thoughts?