# Angular Material 17: How to set custom background color?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm building an Angular app with [Angular Material 17](https://material.angular.io/). My question is very similar to [Angular Material2 theming - how to set app background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43919927/angular-material2-theming-how-to-set-app-background), but the solutions proposed there do not work for me, probably because I'm using a newer version of Angular Material (version 17).

I want to define a custom background color for `.mat-app-background`, but I'm not seeing how to do it. I'm following the examples in the "[Theming your own components](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components#reading-color-values)" documentation, but the background color is always the default one, not the one I define for the theme.

```scss
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

@use "sass:map";

@include mat.core();

$primary-palette: (
  // ...
  900: #0020c6,
  contrast: (
    ...
  )
);

$secondary-palette: (
  ...
  contrast: (
    ...
  )
);

$warn-palette: (
  ...
  contrast: (
    ...
  )
);

// Defining all red for testing purposes.
$custom-background: (
  status-bar: red,
  app-bar: red,
  background: red,
  hover: red,
  card: red,
  dialog: red,
  raised-button: red,
  selected-button: red,
  selected-disabled-button: red,
  disabled-button: red,
  focused-button: red,
  disabled-button-toggle: red,
  unselected-chip: red,
  disabled-list-option: red,
  tooltip: red,
);

$dark-theme: mat.define-dark-theme((
 color: (
   primary: mat.define-palette($primary-palette, 500),
   accent: mat.define-palette($secondary-palette, 500),
   warn: mat.define-palette($warn-palette),
 ),
 typography: mat.define-typography-config(),
 density: 0,
));

$dark-theme: map.merge($dark-theme, (background: $custom-background));

@include mat.core-theme($dark-theme);

@include mat.button-theme($dark-theme);
@include mat.checkbox-theme($dark-theme);

// For debugging.
$background: map.get($dark-theme, background);
$background: map.get($background, background);
@debug $background; // Outputs "red", CORRECT
@debug mat.get-theme-color($dark-theme, background, background); // Outputs #303030, WRONG
@debug mat.get-theme-color($dark-theme, primary, 900); // Outputs #0020c6, CORRECT

.mat-app-background {
  background-color: mat.get-theme-color($dark-theme, background, background); // Outputs #303030, WRONG
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, silly me. The `background` palette is also placed inside the `color` property. So instead of the following:

```scss
$dark-theme: map.merge($dark-theme, (background: $custom-background));
```

I just need to do the following:

```scss
$color-map: map.get($dark-theme, 'color');
$modified-color-map: map.merge($color-map, ('background': $custom-background));
$dark-theme: map.merge($dark-theme, ('color': $modified-color-map));
```